# Python 2 keypress event callback

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi, keypress, keyboard-events

I've a RaspberryPi 3 which will be used headless, and am using https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_DotStar_Pi for controlling LEDs, which constrains me to using Python 2. The LEDs are pretty much the only output of my device, and a single key (specifically a 'w' from a [Bluefruit EZ-Key Bluetooth HID Keyboard Controller](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1535)) is the only input - basically activating or deactivating the lights.

I want to have a callback function be called when a keypress event is detected, to change some state, but all available methods I've found so far (ie reading from `/dev/input/event0`) seem to be blocking. The [python-evdev](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html) module looks useful, but all the async options appear to be Python 3.

In the GPIO python library (which works fine in Python 2) there are callback functions for when a pin changes state, so I guess I'm hoping that there is a similar API for detecting keypress events.

The code will be running in a systemd process, and it seems reading from `/dev/input/event0` is more likely to get me useful key events than `stdin` (which doesn't seem to be hooked up to detect keypresses in systemd processes).

([This question was off-topic](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/46421/6462) for https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ btw )

Answer (score 2):

An input device isn't substantially different from any other file.  You can use `select()` and `poll()` (et al) on it to test if input is available.  That is, given:

```
import select

dev = open('/dev/input/event4')
p = select.poll()
p.register(dev, select.POLLIN)
```

I can check and see if input is available by running:

```
events = p.poll(0)
```

This will either return an empty list, or it will return a list of
`(file descriptor, event)` tuples; in either case it will not block.
Depending on your code, you may actually *want* this to block a
little; the `0` in the above call is actually a timeout (in
milliseconds).

Having received a `POLLIN` event on this file descriptor, I know that
I can `read` some data from it without blocking.  A complete example
might look like:

```
import os
import select

p = select.poll()
dev = open('/dev/input/event4')
p.register(dev, select.POLLIN)

while True:
    events = p.poll(500)
    if events:
        print 'events:', events
        data = os.read(dev.fileno(), 1024)
        print 'read: %s' % (repr(data))
    else:
      print 'no events...'
```

This calls `poll` in a loop, sleeping up to 500 milliseconds each time
unless there is input, in which case it reacts immediately.

I like `select.poll` because the api is easier the the older `select`
call, but I note that that the
[python-evdev](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.org/) module includes
an [example using
select](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#reading-events-from-multiple-devices-using-select).

Taking a closer look at that example, you can actually just pass an
InputDevice to `poll`, so we can rewrite the above like:

```
import os
import select
from evdev import InputDevice

p = select.poll()
dev = InputDevice('/dev/input/event4')

p.register(dev, select.POLLIN)

while True:
    events = p.poll(500)
    if events:
        print 'events:', events
        data = list(dev.read())
        print 'read: %s' % data
```

And see on output something like:

```
events: [(3, 1)]
read: [InputEvent(1461702764L, 854531L, 4, 4, 458789L), InputEvent(1461702764L, 854531L, 1, 9, 1L), InputEvent(1461702764L, 854531L, 0, 0, 0L)]
```

See the [documentation on the `select` module for more
details](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html).

Hopefully that is enough to get you pointed in the right direction.